# Can you assume midpoints in geometry?

Tags: geometry, notation

When you have a diagram such that line segment VY has a point X that looks like it is in the middle of the segment, but the question doesn't state that, can you assume that X is the midpoint of segment VY?

[image]

Comment: Generally, no, you can't. Perhaps you should show an example of a question that makes you want to make such an assumption.

Comment: I wrote one in the description.

Comment: I don't see any diagram. You did not even describe a _specific_ geometry problem where you want $C$ to be the midpoint of $AB$.

Comment: This is an *excellent* question. Thank you for asking it. You have articulated something that I think is a challenge for students of maths. A student needs to learn how to read a problem. One of those challenges is distinguishing between what is stated and what it is easy to incorrectly assume. This is such a challenge that commentators throughout the generations have criticized even Euclid for his lack of rigour. I would recommend studying his geometry and a little commentary to get a feel for this.

Comment: Likewise, one cannot assume two lines are parallel  though they look like to be. Same for perpendiculars.

Comment: The *diagram*, by itself, doesn't even assure you that $V$, $X$, and $Y$ (or $W$, $X$, and $Z$) are collinear.

Comment: You can assume straight angles though.

Comment: No. Don't even assume straight angles. What have you been told about this diagram?

Comment: V and Y are collinear and W and Z are collinear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Even if it *looks* like the midpoint, it should be explicitly stated in the problem description, or you should be able to prove it from other information given. If neither of these cases hold, don't assume you have a midpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can not *assume* anything.

All you can use is
what is explicitly stated
and what you can deduce from that.

If coordinates are stated 
for the points,
and $c$ is equal to
$(a+b)/2$,
then $c$ is the midpoint of
$ab$
and you can use that.

Comment: You can assume some things though, such as that ACB is a straight angle

Comment: If AB is a straight line and C is on AB.